# Using nested controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-resources

Since my site had an admin section and a normal (front-end user) section, I needed to structure the articles controller in such a way that it was RESTful.

So what I did was , have 2 articles controllers, 1 nested under the admin namespace (which would result in admin/articles) and the other one as a normal articles resource (/articles). 
(I followed this [blog](http://www.sentia.com.au/2009/09/when-to-use-nested-controllers-in-your-rails-apps/).)

Now I started facing issues such as

```
A copy of AuditObserver has been removed from the module tree but is still active!
```

2 questions .

1. Is this error really because of me using such a structure of nested resources?
2. Is it a good programming practice to use such a structure? If not, is there a better alternative?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure is perfectly fine, and your code will probably function just fine in production mode.  The issue usually arises in development when modules or classes are not 'unloaded' after a first request. Without seeing the code it's hard to tell exactly which module or plugin might be causing this issue, but you might want to have a look at [this blog post](http://strd6.com/2009/04/cant-dup-nilclass-maybe-try-unloadable/).

You can usually solve this issue by loading the offending module or class only once:

```
config.autoload_once_paths << '/path/to/class/or/module.rb'
```

or by reloading your plugins in development mode:

```
config.reload_plugins = true if Rails.env == 'development'
```